# mongoose schema with dynamic nested Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I'm trying to create a Document Schema where I would have a dynamic Object. Example:

```
var ModuleSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    description : String,
    type : String,
    age : String,
    options : {}
});
```

Is it possible to do the

> options : {}

like that? with any arbitrary attributes inside. I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` when I try to access a route `/api/something` to get all the documents in the collection. It might be because of the way I've defined the schema. any ideas?

EDIT:

```
var Module = require('../models/module');var auth =require('../config/auth');module.exports = function(router,Module){
router
    .get('/api/modules' , auth.checkAuth, function(req,res){
        Module.find(function(err,modules){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.json(modules);
            }
        });
    })
    .post('/api/modules' , auth.checkAuth,function(req,res){
        var module = new Module();
        console.log(req.body);
        module.name = req.body.name;
        module.type = req.body.type;
        module.description = req.body.description;
        module.age = req.body.filename;
        module.options = req.body.options;
        module.save(function(err,module){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.json({ id : module._id});
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the schema. Could you paste your route code?

Comment: the error is in Module.find(), could "Module" namespace be used for something else? that's why the conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this.

```
// Importing the Users Mongoose Scheme
 var User       = require('../app/models/user');
 var Feed      = require('../app/models/ufeed');

 module.exports = function(app) {


// A Route to get all users info
app.get('/user/all', function(req, res) {
// use mongoose to get all users in the database
User.find(function(err, user) 
{
    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
    // return all todos in JSON format
    res.json(user);

   });
});
```

Within my server.js file I am creating an app like so.

```
 var app      = express();
```

And then passing it to my routes file.

```
 require('./app/routes.js')(app); // load our routes and pass in our app
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes that is a solution, but I'm passing (app) as (router)  but the problem was that for some reason... I was also passing Module  , module.exports = function(router,Module) {...}, that was overwriting the Module =require(...) on the top. thank you for the tip it help me search in that line of code.

Comment: yes, I also changed Module to SomethingElse so it wont conflict.